# How do I create a two column layout using xaml RelativePanel?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, relativepanel

I'd really like to use RelativePanel in a UWP app I'm writing, to simplify visual state.

This is what I want

[image]

I've tried to achieve this with the following XAML:

```
<RelativePanel>

    <TextBlock x:Name="Title" Height="50" Margin="15" FontSize="24"
        RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True" 
        RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" 
        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
    </TextBlock>

    <TextBox x:Name="Editor" Margin="15" Padding="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" 
        RelativePanel.Below="Title" 
        RelativePanel.RightOf="FileList">
    </TextBox>  

    <ListView x:Name="FileList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="15"
        RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" 
        RelativePanel.Below="Title">
    </ListView>

</RelativePanel>
```

This isn't working. `Editor` does not stretch. If I set `Editor` to `RelativePanel.AlignRightWith="FilesList"`, it stretches past files list and fills the window.

Is there any way to do what I want with `RelativePanel`? Please don't post suggestions on how to do this in `Grid`, I can already do that - I want to use `RelativePanel` in this case

Answer (score 1):

Your `Editor` control should have -

```
RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
RelativePanel.Below="Title"
RelativePanel.LeftOf="FileList"
RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
```

Note it should be `LeftOf`, not `RightOf`. You will also need `AlignBottomWithPanel` set to `True`.